# How do I add an artifact to a local maven repository so that it will properly reference its own set of dependencies?

Tags: maven

I am developing an application that depends on a number of legacy JAR files and I want the project to build straight out of version control without other users having to install these JARs in their local repository. I cannot add them to the corporate repository so I have created a repository that is local to this project and I have added these JARs to that repository using maven-install-plugin:install-file and setup the repository entry in the POM file so it knows to search the local repository.

This works exactly the way I want...up to a point. The problem is that most of these legacy JAR files have their own set of dependencies. I would like for them to work just like other artifacts that have their own set of dependencies so that maven can resolve everything and include all the necessary files but I can't find a way to do this with any maven-install-plugin:install-file options (or any other maven commands/plugins). I am pretty new at maven so I am probably just ignorant on this point.

As a work around, I attempted to go into the local repository directory and manually edit the POM file for the artifact to include the dependencies. This didn't cause any errors but it is also not pulling in those dependencies.

Can someone out there give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maven-install-plugin:install-file` goal has a [pomFile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#pomFile) attribute.  You can use this to specify a POM file for your legacy jar.  You would create a POM file that points to all of the dependencies by artifactId in the `<dependencies>` section.  If you have a remote nexus repository you can use the admin screen for the repository to deploy a jar.

Answer (score 1):

Once you edit POM files in your project specific repository, host it as maven repo using Maven Repository Managers (like sonatype nexus).  Add your project nexus repo as one of the maven repo in project pom.xml  as below

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-project-mvn-repo</id>
        <name>my-project-mvn-repo</name>
        <url>http://<your project maven repo URL here></url>
    </repository>
    <repositories>
```

Now all developers should be able to make build. The legacy jar files POM contains dependency. Maven should take care of automatically pulling dependent jars on developer's workspace.

Comment: So, in order for the dependents-of-dependents feature to work, the repository has to be hosted?  I thought maven would do that even when pulling from a local non-hosted repository.

Comment: when you install in local repository using maven-install-plugin:install-file, I think it only installs that specific jar file. You have to go through maven pull path I guess to get dependencies.  Also, you can avoid manual edit in repository and use commandline option "pomFile" to install-file and pass POM file containing dependencies. (Ref :  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) . If you pass pomFile command line , it MIGHT pull dependents during installation automatically.. not sure. If it doesn't pull, you might have to host a repo.